# Aspose Imaging Image opitions constructor

Tags: c#, .net, aspose

I have install new version of As Pose Imaging Assembly(version  17.7.0.0) and i need rewrite the code so that it will support new version Assembly below if the I need to rewrite
 As it does not accept default constructor 
Issue is with tiff options code

```
public void ImageToTIFF(string imagePath, string outputPath, string server, string folder, int sequenceNumber)
    {
        int page = 0;
        using (Aspose.Imaging.Image inputImage = Aspose.Imaging.Image.Load(imagePath))
        {
            page++;
            Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.TiffOptions tiffSaveOptions = new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.TiffOptions();
            tiffSaveOptions.Compression = Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Tiff.Enums.TiffCompressions.CcittFax4;
            tiffSaveOptions.Photometric = Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Tiff.Enums.TiffPhotometrics.MinIsBlack;
            tiffSaveOptions.BitsPerSample = new ushort[] {1};
            tiffSaveOptions.Palette = Aspose.Imaging.ColorPaletteHelper.CreateMonochrome();

            // Get the pixels of image by specifying the area as image boundary
            Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage image = inputImage as Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage;
            Aspose.Imaging.Color[] imageColors = image.LoadPixels(inputImage.Bounds);
            int power;
            for (int i = 0; i <= imageColors.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    power = (int)imageColors[i].R + (int)imageColors[i].G + (int)imageColors[i].B;
                    if (power < 380)
                    {
                        imageColors[i] = Aspose.Imaging.Color.White;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        imageColors[i] = Aspose.Imaging.Color.Black;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("i: {0}, imageColors[i].R: {1}, imageColors[i].G: {2}, imageColors[i].B: {3}", i, imageColors[i].R, imageColors[i].G, imageColors[i].B);
                    Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                    imageColors[i] = Aspose.Imaging.Color.White;
                }
            }

            Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage imagePixels = inputImage as Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage;
            imagePixels.SavePixels(inputImage.Bounds, imageColors);
            inputImage.Save(outputPath + FileCreateTime(new FileInfo(imagePath)) + "_" + server + "_" + folder + "_" + sequenceNumber.ToString("D6") + "_" + page.ToString("D4") + ".tif", tiffSaveOptions);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because no effort is made, this is just a "please convert my code" topic.

Comment: If you upgrade the code, read all release notes between your previous version and the new version. Aspose generally explains how to resolve this issue (they first deprecate the code before actually removing it).

Answer (score 0):

I have observed your requirements and like to share that there is no default empty constructor available for [TiffOptions](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/imaging/aspose.imaging.imageoptions/tiffoptions) class in Aspose.Imaging. I suggest you to please try using following alternate sample code on your end to serve the purpose.

```
public void ImageToTIFF(string imagePath, string outputPath, string server, string folder, int sequenceNumber)
{
    int page = 0;
    using (Aspose.Imaging.Image inputImage = Aspose.Imaging.Image.Load(imagePath))
    {
        page++;
        Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.TiffOptions tiffSaveOptions = new Aspose.Imaging.ImageOptions.TiffOptions(TiffExpectedFormat.Default);
        tiffSaveOptions.Compression = Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Tiff.Enums.TiffCompressions.CcittFax4;
        tiffSaveOptions.Photometric = Aspose.Imaging.FileFormats.Tiff.Enums.TiffPhotometrics.MinIsBlack;
        tiffSaveOptions.BitsPerSample = new ushort[] { 1 };
        tiffSaveOptions.Palette = Aspose.Imaging.ColorPaletteHelper.CreateMonochrome();

        // Get the pixels of image by specifying the area as image boundary
        Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage image = inputImage as Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage;
        Aspose.Imaging.Color[] imageColors = image.LoadPixels(inputImage.Bounds);
        int power;
        for (int i = 0; i <= imageColors.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                power = (int)imageColors[i].R + (int)imageColors[i].G + (int)imageColors[i].B;
                if (power < 380)
                {
                    imageColors[i] = Aspose.Imaging.Color.White;
                }
                else
                {
                    imageColors[i] = Aspose.Imaging.Color.Black;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("i: {0}, imageColors[i].R: {1}, imageColors[i].G: {2}, imageColors[i].B: {3}", i, imageColors[i].R, imageColors[i].G, imageColors[i].B);
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                imageColors[i] = Aspose.Imaging.Color.White;
            }
        }

        Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage imagePixels = inputImage as Aspose.Imaging.RasterImage;
        imagePixels.SavePixels(inputImage.Bounds, imageColors);
        inputImage.Save(outputPath + FileCreateTime(new FileInfo(imagePath)) + "_" + server + "_" + folder + "_" + sequenceNumber.ToString("D6") + "_" + page.ToString("D4") + ".tif", tiffSaveOptions);
    }
}
```

I hope the shared information will be helpful.

I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Many Thanks,